# How does * operator work in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I know that it expands function arguments, but if I try something like this in Python 2:

```
x = [1,2,3]
print *x # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
print [*x] # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So it appears that I am missing something about what * exactly does?

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: `print` is not a function in python 2, it's a statement. And a list literal isn't a function either.

Comment: `[*x]` _is_ legal syntax... But only in Python 3.

Comment: Python 2, edited original question.

Comment: Despite your terminal question mark, you are not actually asking a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` operator, unpacks the elements from a sequence/iterable (for example, list or tuple) as positional arguments to a function

On python2, `print` is a statement and not a function. So import print function from future, so that you use `*` operator for unpacking a list elements as arguments

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print (*x)
1 2 3
```

On python3, `print` is a function. So you can use `*` operator straight-away

```
>>> print (*x)
1 2 3
```